# Why html_entity_decode() decodes "&oacute;" incorrectly?

Tags: php

Why `html_entity_decode()` decodes "ó" to unknown character?

`echo "&oacute; -> ".html_entity_decode('&oacute;');`

Gives the following result:

`ó -> �`

in raw format (not interpretated by browser):

`&oacute; -> �`

Charset is UTF8.

Comment: Make sure you're using UTF-8 **all the way through** your system. It's no use having UTF-8 on your HTML page if the PHP code isn't saved as UTF-8 or the DB isn't using UTF-8, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of default encoding which is `ISO-8859-1` (for PHP before 5.4). Set it to `UTF-8` in third argument of `html_entity_decode`.

Comment: Oh didn't notice that note about changes in version. Thank you.